# Can I return a list of strings from a Postgres function?

Tags: postgresql

I have a materialized view in Postgres like

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

But `('a', 'b', 'c')` is part of my business logic, and I want to be able to make it into `('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')` or `('a')` without having to drop `my_view` and recreate it, since it has a bunch of dependent views. So I want to replace the definition of `my_view` to something like

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column NOT IN my_unwanted_list();
```

And then `my_unwanted_list` would just return a constant that I could set to whatever I want by updating `my_unwanted_list`'s definition. Then I can add an unwanted value just by updating `my_unwanted_list` and refreshing `my_view`.

But I am having some trouble getting the syntax right for `my_unwanted_list`. How do I write a PostgreSql function that returns something I can use in an `IN` filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the values in an [array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html), and compare against its elements using the [`ANY()` / `ALL()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20350) constructs:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_unwanted_list() RETURNS TEXT[] AS $$
  SELECT ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c']
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view AS
  SELECT * FROM my_table
  WHERE my_column <> ALL(my_unwanted_list());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your function to return the results of a query, or you rather use `IN` instead of `<>ALL(array)` (as @NickBarnes suggests), you can do the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_unwanted_list() RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS $$
  SELECT col
  FROM table
  WHERE condition
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view AS
  SELECT * FROM my_table
  WHERE my_column NOT IN (SELECT my_unwanted_list());
```